# How to set universal time

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on C# .net windows application, Need to keep in time of persons who login using application,
i have Used

```
Datetime.Now;
```

to take current time when person login,and its working fine.

But problem is that when any person come and change the time of Computer system and then login it takes that changed time, and i agree that am using

```
Datetime.now;
```

So it takes that changed time, but is there any when he lgin then universal will be take into account for his/her intime.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "universal" time? The only time the computer knows is the system's, which is returned by DateTime.Now. Are you talking about daylight or timezone changes?

Comment: The usual way would be to use some *servers* time - or just use the usual domain system (TBH: nobody would use a client-side tool to protocol log-in times - just let the users log on to your domain and read the logs on your DC)

Comment: Are you looking to [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) ?

Comment: cant we use universal time ?? Suppose Now Its 2.30 pm but someone come and change it as 1.30 and login ... at that time his in time should be 2.30

Comment: @aloisdg UTC would not help at all - the problem is that the user can trick the system by manipulating the local clock ;)

Comment: There's no such thing as "universal time". There are the time values returned by various systems and servers. In a domain, the DC sets the time of all member computers. On a standalone machine, the administrator can change it to anything.

Comment: @ChetanBodke why don't you talk to your IT guys? Even if you don't want to use the administrative tools/logs you can ask them to just disable the access to the local clock for users

Comment: @CarstenKönig just read again the question. I misunderstood it.

Comment: If your application uses a database server, set the time on the server's side, eg with a calculated column.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos for example ?

Comment: Depends on the database, but in SQL Server you can add a column to your table with default value `GETDATE()` or `GETUTCDATE()`.

Comment: I think you wnant your application to use a time Server instead of the local time on the computer so a hacker can't change the time on the local computer and get a different time from the actual time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only "universal time" that exists is UTC. You can query it by using:

```
var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

If you need to display it as a local time (taking time zone into account) you can then use:

```
utc.ToLocalTime();
```

Now this doesn't fix your issue since it is still based on the system time. Anybody with enough permission can change the system time. Your only option would be to ask a web service (like a time server) for the current (and real) UTC time. But I don't think that it is practical for logging purpose.